# "Update item" action in SharePoint Designer 2010 on a List

Tags: workflow, list, workflow-activity

Is my logic correct or am I going crazy.

I have a few conditions before using the Update item action in SPD 2010.  Example below:

If **A** equals **1**

and **B** equals **2**

and **C** equals **3**

and **Date1** is greater than **Date2**

**Update item** in Current List *(Find column1 equals to Apples, set column1 to Oranges)*

then Email Person1

then Stop Workflow and log Changed Apples to Oranges.

Else

Stop Workflow and log No change to list item.

The problem I have is that it updates all items in my list from Apples to Oranges even when the conditions are all FALSE.  I know the conditions work as it didn't send an email to Person1 and it skipped to the Else statement.

What am I doing wrong?  It seems like Update Item action is not part of/dependent upon the conditions at all.

Note: I have a script that goes through each item and update and kicks off the workflow.

Comment: Is 'and' supported in SharePoint designer workflow?

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your workflow actions. I think you did something wrong in scope of the loop.

Comment: Yes, and is a supported evaluator.